# 10 pixel square brush in Gimp... how?

Tags: gimp

I need a brush that is exactly 10x10 pixels.

Here is what I have tried so far:

- creating a brush with a radius of 5. This, of course, results in a brush that is more than 10 pixels wide
- creating a brush that is 3.5 pixels wide, since looks like radius measures the diagonal of the square (a^2 + a^2 = 25, a ≈ 3.53). This creates a brush that is 9 pixels wide.
- use scale to scale up or down the brush size. It stays at 9 pixels square, then jumps to 11 pixels square, without stopping at 10 pixels in between

It seems, to me, a bit crazy that I can't do this. Has anyone successfully created a square brush that is 10x10 pixels in size?

Comment: have you seen this? http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Custom_Brushes/

Comment: That might work! What I ended up doing was scaling the image 90% :)

Comment: so i am putting this as an answer so you can close this question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create custom brushes using three methods.

Simple shapes are created using the button labelled New at the bottom of the brush selection dialog.

Complex black and white brushes can be created by saving a grayscale image as using the .gbr file extension. The content of such a brush is treated line an alpha-channel.

This means that any pixel that is pure white is treated as transparent. However, in this tutoria we will be creating brushes that use pictures with colour and this brush will also have multiple images.

You should follow this guidelines while making custom brush in gimp :

[Gimp Custom Brush Tutorial](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Custom_Brushes/)

Hope this will help.....

Comment: Well, the tutorial is for creating a multi-colored brush, which is something I'm not interested in. But maybe the .gbr file is the answer...

Comment: Creating .gbr is the way to do it. If you're on a Mac, save it to /Applications/Gimp.app/Resources/share/gimp/2.0/brushes/

Answer (score 3):

In more recent GIMP versions - 2.8 and onwards:

- use the 1x1px brush, or any size square brushes that is based on the VBR format (create a new brush in the brushes dialog, if in doubt)
- set the size to 10 in the paint tool you are using

Note that it depends on the tool what you will get - the paintbrush tool will add additional semi-transparent pixels depending on the sub-pixel pointer position on the canvas, the pencil tool will use the exact size and will produce squares that are fully aligned with the pixel grid.